# Clarification while using axis2-wsdl2java-approach

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis

I am trying to use axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin for auto generating the server side class files from a wsdl. 
I am not sure how to implement the SkeletonInterface to call the business logic. There is an auto-generated Skeleton file which implements the interface, but it has a un-implemented method in it.
The problem is that I am not allowed to modify auto-gen files hence not sure on how to implement the method.

Below are the things that I have tried:

Few issues that I am facing:

i.  Tried to rename the interface implementation class and call it through service.xml, but the new impl was not being called. (AuthenticatedServicesValidSkeletonImpl.java)

ii. Tried to extend the Skeleton class, but got null pointer exception while deploying the application and there was nothing much which I could get from the logs.

iii.    Tried with cfx plugin for auto-generation of classes as well, but getting similar issues in it.

Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your business logic in the un-implemented method in the `AuthenticatedServicesValidSkeletonImpl.java`. This will provide you a POJO of Request, and at the end, you need to return back a POJO of Response which will then be serialized into the WebService Response. The Request and Response objects are already created by WSDL2java, you just need to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs pradeep. I have tried that and it is working if i put my business logic in the auto-generated file. But  the problem is that I am not allowed to modify auto-gen files as per my client standards hence not sure on how to implement the method. Any idea on how to write and use custom files which could use this auto-gen files as it is.

Comment: Can you give an example what is stopping you from using the generated files?

Comment: The auto-gen file has a method and the content of the method is like below: 

`throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement " + this.getClass().getName() + "#xxx");`

In my project, we use SONAR for checking the CQA, and as per WebService standards follwed here, we are not supposed to edit the auto-generated files. Hence i am not sure how to extend/implement this class and then use this auto-gen file while run time to complete the flow.